# Determining if string B could be the result of a deletion/addition to string A

Tags: python, string, algorithm, insertion

Assume I have a base string of length 29, and a list of arbitrary strings of lengths 28 and 30. How would I determine the number of these strings which could be the result of a deletion/addition of one character performed on the base string?

I'm doing this in Python, for the record.

Comment: I'm actually asking for the algorithm. I can write the code myself.

And this isn't for a homework assignment. I'm trying to compare a set of sequenced aptomers (29-base pair gene sequences) to a known one, determining if the difference is due to a sequencing error or not.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: There are a number of [Approximate String Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) algorithms that can be used to solve this

Comment: Well, a single insertion or deletion of a single character would result in a string that has both a prefix and a suffix that still matches a prefix or suffix respectively of the original string, one of which may be zero-length, but not both. The lengths of the prefix and suffix should add up to the original length plus/minus 1. Perhaps that fact suggests how you might proceed in developing an algorithm to check it...

Comment: The Levenshtein distance algorithm suits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see... I would modify the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (Python code [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python)) to make it work only in case of addition or deletion of one character.

```
from functools import partial

from my_distances import **add_delete_distance**

def is_accepted(base_string, alternative_string):
    '''It uses the custom distance algorithm to evaluate (boolean output) if a
    particular alternative string is ok with respect to the base string.'''
    assert type(alternative_string) == str
    len_difference = abs(len(base_string)-len(alternative_string))
    if len_difference == 1 :
        distance = add_delete_distance(base_string, alternative_string)
        if distance == 1:
            return True
    return False

base_string = 'michele'
alternative_strings = ['michel', 'michelle', 'james', 'michela']

print filter(partial(is_accepted, base_string), alternative_string)
```

What do you think about it?